# Custom tab completion in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

When adding event subscribers in a .NET 3.5 project in Visual Studio 2017, I noticed that you can have a subscriber auto-generate by hitting tab after typing `+=`:

[image]

It's also smart enough to generate the placeholder function in the class scope.

I would like to have similar behavior for a custom interface, but it would have similar requirements:

1. Generate a placeholder function in the current class scope.
2. Some reflection that allows the generated function to take arguments based on the input (such as the delegate signature, event and class names being used to create the placeholder function)
3. Native .NET 3.5 in Visual Studio 2017 - no 3rd party plugins.

How would I go about doing so? I'm aware of snippets, but feel they may not be able to meet requirement 2 listed above.

Comment: Have you tried looking up the "+=" snippet and see how they implement it?

Comment: It feels too complex to be a snippet. After a bit more research I'm pretty certain that this could be done using the 'quick action' or "light bulb" system https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn903708.aspx - but I haven't had a chance to try and implement that yet.